# Incorrect result in JavaScript calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

the below java-script code supposed to get order amount and total amount of order after adding the delivery charge to the order amount.

**Example**

```
Order Amount = 25
Delivery charge = 5
Total Amount  = 30
```

Delivery charge comes from label control in asp.

But when i applied the blow code i got these results.

```
Order Amount = 25
Delivery charge = 5
Total Amount  = 255
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function multInputs() {
                var $mult = 0;
                var $multGrand = 0;
                var $multCharge = 0;
                $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
                    var $UnitPrice = $('.UnitPrice', this).val();
                    var $Quantity = $('.Quantity', this).val();
                    var $total = (($UnitPrice) * ($Quantity));

                    $mult += $total;
                    $multCharge = $mult + $('#<%= lbldcharge.ClientID %>').text();

                });

                $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
                    var $UnitPrice = $('.UnitPrice', this).val();
                    var $Quantity = $('.Quantity', this).val();
                    var $total = (($UnitPrice) * ($Quantity));

                    $('.multTotal', this).text(parseFloat($total).toFixed(2));

                });
                $(".lblGrandAmount").text(parseFloat($mult).toFixed(2));
                $(".lblChrageAmount").text(parseFloat($multCharge).toFixed(2));

            }

            $(".txtMult input").on('keyup mouseup', multInputs);
            function multInputs() {
                var $mult = 0;
                var $multGrand = 0;
                var $multCharge = 0;
                $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
                    var $UnitPrice = $('.UnitPrice', this).val();
                    var $Quantity = $('.Quantity', this).val();
                    var $total = (($UnitPrice) * ($Quantity));

                    $mult += $total;
                    $multCharge = $mult + $('#<%= lbldcharge.ClientID %>').text();


                });

                $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
                    var $UnitPrice = $('.UnitPrice', this).val();
                    var $Quantity = $('.Quantity', this).val();
                    var $total = (($UnitPrice) * ($Quantity));


                    $('.multTotal', this).text(parseFloat($total).toFixed(2));

                });
                $(".lblGrandAmount").text(parseFloat($mult).toFixed(2));

                $(".lblChrageAmount").text(parseFloat($multCharge).toFixed(2));
            }
        });

    </script>
```

**Label**

```
<asp:Label ID="lbldcharge" runat="server" Text="5"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: 255 results from adding strings "25" and "5" - you need to use Numbers (parseFloat)

Comment: Looks like one of the operands is a string so they are being concatenated as strings, not added as numbers.

Comment: you need to parse your values to `parseInt/parseFloat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string concatenation happening with + operator.

parseInt or parseFloat before adding

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
$multCharge = $mult + $('#<%= lbldcharge.ClientID %>').text()
```

to

```
$multCharge = $mult + parseFloat($('#<%= lbldcharge.ClientID %>').text())
```